# How to replicate Lightning experience account page in Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to replicate lightning experience Account page using lightning component, I am able to acheive the top part but not able to do down one(Related and Details) can anyone help me with this? 
[image]

Comment: You may want to think in terms of separate components for each part of what you want to do and build them up using "blocks". That's the who idea behind components. Now that I've seen your edit, most definitely you want to use separate component blocks for related items and details.

Comment: How can i can show & hide details when Related or Details is clicked?

Comment: You need to use an event handler for that.